# Android time interval percentage

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have three date objects - startDate, endDate, currentDate. They represent the start/end of a time interval, and the curent date. I would like to know what percentage does the currentDate represents (x), if currentDate is bewtween the startDate and endDate.
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the percentage by using `.getTime()` on each date:

```
double start = (double)StartDate.getTime();
double end = (double)EndDate.getTime();
double cur = (double)CurrentDate.getTime();

double percent = ((cur - start) / (end - start)) * 100f;
```

EDIT: added `* 100f` due to it being a percentage, not decimal...